# angularJS + mongoose: TypeError: Cannot read property 'model' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongoose

I have a simple express app, that's supposed to provide an endpoint for posting some content. Upon calling $http in my controller I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'model' of undefined
>       at new model (C:\Webpages\veryNiceWords\API\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:738:17)
>       at C:\Webpages\veryNiceWords\API\api.js:24:17
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Webpages\veryNiceWords\API\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (C:\Webpages\veryNiceWords\API\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (C:\Webpages\veryNiceWords\API\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Webpages\veryNiceWords\API\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at C:\Webpages\veryNiceWords\API\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
>       at Function.process_params (C:\Webpages\veryNiceWords\API\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
>       at next (C:\Webpages\veryNiceWords\API\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
>       at C:\Webpages\veryNiceWords\API\api.js:16:2
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Webpages\veryNiceWords\API\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at trim_prefix (C:\Webpages\veryNiceWords\API\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
>       at C:\Webpages\veryNiceWords\API\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
>       at Function.process_params (C:\Webpages\veryNiceWords\API\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
>       at next (C:\Webpages\veryNiceWords\API\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
>       at C:\Webpages\veryNiceWords\API\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:129:5

I have no idea what this means, or how to fix it. Can somebody please have a look at my code and point out what I'm doing wrong?

api.js (the express app)

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Words = require('./models/words.js');
//initialize our express app
var app = express();
//use body parser with JSON
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//middleware for CORS requests
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');

    next();
});

//register endpoint
app.post('/API/addWords', function(req, res) {
    //get user from request body
    var words = req.body;

    var newWords = new Words.model({
        author: words.author,
        source: words.source,
        quote: words.quote
    });

    newWords.save(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;

    console.log('words saved!');
    });
});

//connect to mongoDB
mongoose.connect('');

//define our server
var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('api listening on ', server.address().port);
});
```

words.js (the model required by the api)

```
// grab the things we need
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// create a schema
var wordsSchema = new Schema({
  author: String,
  source: String,
  quote: String
});

var Words = mongoose.model('Words', wordsSchema);

// make this available to our users in our Node applications
module.exports = Words;
```

the frontend html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <form ng-submit="submit()">
                <label for="author">Author:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="author" ng-model="author" placeholder="Maya Angelou">
                <br>
                <label for="source">Source:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="source" ng-model="source" placeholder="I know why the caged bird sings">
                <br>
                <label for="quote">Quote:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" id="quote" ng-model="quote" placeholder="There is no greater agony than bearing an untold story inside you"></textarea>
                <br>
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
                    <input class="btn btn-default postQuote" type="submit" value="Quote it"></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <p>{{ author }}</p>
    <p>{{ source }}</p>
    <p>{{ quote }}</p>
</div>
```

the front-end controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('frontEndApp')
    .controller('AddwordsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.submit = function() {

            var url = 'http://localhost:3000/API/addWords';
            var words = {
                author: $scope.author,
                source: $scope.source,
                quote: $scope.quote
            };

            $http.post(url, words)
                .success(function(res) {
                    console.log('posted quote!');
                })
                .error(function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });
        };
    });
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is problem in `var newWords = new Words.model({` , it should be `var newWords = new Words({`

`new Words.model(` is not required. Only `new Words(` is required.

Please correct the code.

Answer (score 0):

You want your controller endpoint for '/API/addWords' to look like this:

```
app.post('/API/addWords', function(req, res) {
  //get user from request body
  var words = req.body;

  var newWords = new Words({
    author: words.author,
    source: words.source,
    quote: words.quote
  });

  newWords.save(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('words saved!');
  });

});
```

You don't need the extra 'model'.